# Setting Java path using bash script CentOs 7

Tags: java, bash, centos7, java-home

I'm trying to change the path of java_home to java-1.7.0 in a CentOS 7 machine which already has java-1.8.0 installed.

I uninstalled java-1.8.0, and used

> yum -y install java-1.7.0

to install java 1.7. However,

> which java

command still points to java-1.8. How do I find the path of java 1.7 JRE in this case in order to set java_home using a bash script?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Try setting JAVA_HOME with the new java path(eg. '/usr/local/java1.7/jdk').

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java1.7/jdk
```

Then add the JAVA_HOME/bin to PATH variable.

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

By default java will get installed in the ' /usr/lib/jvm ' location.
So, try ls command in this path to find the required java version.

```
cd  /usr/lib/jvm
ls
```

Use this path to set the JAVA_HOME.

Comment: my Java home looks like "java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242.b08-0.el7_7.x86_64/jre". I need to know how to get where Java 1.7 is installed in the system using bash programmatically to set the path using the export command.